# Why is Timestamp onEdit Script not working with my dropdown menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I'm trying to display a timestamp when a specific cell (which happens to be a drop-down list, horizontally-merged across multiple columns) is edited, but have not been able to get it to work.

Here's what I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  addTimestamp(e);
  
}


function addTimestamp(e){
  //variable
  var startRow = 6;
  var targetColumn = 7;
  
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow){
    
    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.sourcegetActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(currentDate);
  }
  
}
```

[Here's a test sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3rlpX-rcKYX7UyKf44duEvTBzTg048w8lQWD94Q3Lc/edit?usp=sharing)

I would also like it to be able to skip over 4 tabs, but apply to the rest. I had originally tried using

```
e.sourcegetActiveSheet().getName() != "*tab I wanna exclude*" &&
```

within the IF, but don't know if that works since I can't get the full script to run properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

You wrote your code where you get the activesheet incorrectly. In your code, you put e.sourcegetActiveSheet() but it should be e.source.getActiveSheet().

### Solution

Please replace the said line of code with the code below. I've tested it on my end and it is working correctly.

```
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(currentDate);
```

Once done, you can test your code about skipping tabs.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! The skipping tabs portion is now working as well, thank you!

Comment: That sounds great! Will appreciate it if you will accept this answer in order for others to know which one solved your problem. Happy coding! :)